# Move the external coordinates of polygon to vector boundary

Tags: python, shapefile, polygon, geopandas, shapely

I'm new to Python and I want to move all the outer vertices of the polygon, up to the boundary of the vector below. I thought it could be done through the affine function of shapely but I'm not sure. Fill the edge without moving the vertices.

```
import geopandas as gpd
import shapely

poly = #shp with vertices to expand
boundary_geom = #shp of the border


boundary_geom 

geometry
0   POLYGON ((673590.000 4955020.000, 673540.000 4...

poly  

    geometry    class
1   POLYGON ((673180.000 4955400.000, 673180.000 4...   3
2   POLYGON ((673410.000 4955360.000, 673410.000 4...   3
3   POLYGON ((673500.000 4955340.000, 673500.000 4...   3
4   POLYGON ((673670.000 4955310.000, 673670.000 4...   3
6   POLYGON ((673100.000 4955370.000, 673120.000 4...   3
7   POLYGON ((673210.000 4955390.000, 673240.000 4...   1
8   POLYGON ((673250.000 4955190.000, 673260.000 4...   2
10  POLYGON ((673420.000 4955300.000, 673430.000 4...   2
11  POLYGON ((673530.000 4955100.000, 673540.000 4...   1


for idx,row in enumerate(poly.geometry):
    poly.geometry[idx]= shapely.affinity.scale(boundary_geom.geometry.iloc[0], xfact=1, yfact=1,zfact=1, origin='center')
```

[image]

This is the output, but only on the last geometry of the polygon:

[image]

Comment: How badly does it have to be a polygon to expand out to? If you used the Euclidian Allocation tool in ArcMap that would fill the gap and apportion the polygons correctly, but this is a raster tool, set it to a small cell resolution.

Comment: ArcMap not used but a few lines of python. The goal is to make the outer vertices of the blue polygon extend to the edge of the black polygon.

Comment: The line of code I wrote loops over each geometry, but just fills in the blanks without expanding the vertices. Maybe even a tween could help in your opinion? Using python would be ideal.

Comment: Maybe buffer, clip with the rectangle, find a way of removing the overlaps

Comment: With the buffer you will extend all the vertigos of each geometry, I am interested in moving only the external ones of the blue shapefile

Answer (score -1):

This solution takes a raster based approach which I believe is the most suitable solution to this spatial problem. It would be interesting to see if anyone else offers a purely vector base solution?

Below uses the [Euclidean Allocation](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/euclidean-allocation.htm) tool in ArcMap. This can be called within a python script if so desired but I show the same logic running in model builder (which can of cause be converted into python).

Here is your starting data, the polygons within the exterior boundary were derived from a raster dataset that was 10m resolution. Each polygon is colour code by its class. I want to be using the allocation tool at a smaller resolution, so in this case I use 1m.

[image: Starting data]

The model:

[image: The model]

The results (having converted back into polygons):

[image: Results]

The conversion back to polygons had simplify parameter turned on to smooth edges. The conversion from raster to polygon will inevitable introduce sliver gaps which can be reduce if you use a finer cell size but that won't eliminate all of them but that may be an acceptable level of error for you? If not I would be exploring the union tool followed by the eliminate tool to attempt to close the gaps.

If ArcMap is not a viable solution for you I'm sure some of these steps could be run in QGIS calling GDAL?